# How to detect if an Android device has been touched or moved 

Tags: android, device

Is it possible to know if the phone has been touched/moved (lifting it for example), using some Events?
How would you code it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to the Sensors API in android. You can find info about the orientation of the device. Here's the guide i used. Thanks to Marko Gargenta

http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/43.html